# Remove MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller, hidden, opacity

I am using the **MPMoviePlayerController** to play a movie from the web.
Depending on the table row selected a different movie is loaded. However, i would like the **MPMoviePlayerController** to **disappear** (**or hide** itself), once a new row is selected.

Here is the code that gets called to play my movie and to, eventually, hide it

```
- (IBAction) playMovie{
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:vidMovie];
moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];  
moviePlayer.view.frame = vidPlayer.frame;// CGRectMake(64, 624, 640, 360);
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
[moviePlayer play];
}

- (void) hidePlayer{
[moviePlayer stop];
[moviePlayer release];
}
```

in my .h i declare moviePlayer as such

```
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;
```

I've tried setting the moviePlayer **frame height and width to 0** but that still shows the play button.
I've tried the variables **.hidden** and **.opaque** and still i get nothing

Could anyone help me figure out what i might have forgotten. Any help would be greatly appreciated! 
*Thanks*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it after trying all sorts of different things...

Seems i needed to retain my moviePlyer to be able to remove it in another part of my code. 
If anyone has the same problem, here is my solution!

```
- (IBAction) playMovie{
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:vidMovie];
moviePlayer = [[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:url] retain]; 
moviePlayer.view.frame = vidPlayer.frame;// CGRectMake(64, 624, 640, 360);
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
[moviePlayer play];
}

- (void) hidePlayer{
[moviePlayer stop];
[moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Hope this might be able to help othes!